# Maximum length of reply-to header

Tags: email, maxlength, email-headers

Is there a maximum length for the `reply-to` header field? The maximum length for a e-mail address is defined but in `reply-to` you can add several addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding latest [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3) documentation

> 2.2.3.  Long Header Fields
>
> Each header field is logically a single line of characters
> comprising    the field name, the colon, and the field body.  For
> convenience    however, and to deal with the 998/78 character
> limitations per line,    the field body portion of a header field can
> be split into a    multiple-line representation; this is called
> "folding".  The general    rule is that wherever this specification
> allows for folding white    space (not simply WSP characters), a CRLF
> may be inserted before any    WSP.